# How to connect to a TCP Socket, send data for authorization before receiving data

Tags: c#, sockets, system.reactive

I am using Rx to connect to a Socket and receive data. The issue I have is that after connecting to the Socket I need to send data for authorization before data can be received.

**Connection**

```
public static IObservable<Unit> WhenConnected(this Socket socket, IPAddress address, int port)
{
    return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<IPAddress, int>(
        socket.BeginConnect,
        socket.EndConnect)(address, port);
}
```

**Receive Data**

Won't post all the code but in summary it uses TakeWhile to repeatedly receive bytes from the Begin/End Receive async methods.

```
var receiveData = Observable.FromAsyncPattern
    <byte[], int, int, SocketFlags, int>(socket.BeginReceive, socket.EndReceive);
```

**Question 1:**

Now my issue is how do I go about constructing my subscription?

```
var query = from _ in socket.WhenConnected(IPAddress.Parse(_host), _port)
            //need to authorize before receiving data
            from value socket.DataReceived().Repeat()
            select value;

using (query.Subscribe(...
```

**Question 2**

Usually I would send packets of information using a NetworkStream rather than a Socket so would I need to do something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

The [Rxx library](http://rxx.codeplex.com/) has some extension methods that are very helpful for this sort of operation. Inside the [StreamExtensions.cs](http://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65668#1100688) of version 1.3, there is

```
public static IObservable<byte[]> ReadObservable(this Stream stream, int count)
```

and

```
public static IObservable<Unit> WriteObservable(this Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```

which can be used on a network stream. I'm not sure if the following is the best way, but it could be set up as follows:

```
NetworkStream networkStream = null;
var setupStreamPlan = Observable
  .When(WhenConnected(...))
  .Then(_ => networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket));
var authorizePlan = Observable
  .When(setupStreamPlan)
  .Then(_ => networkStream.WriteObserable(/*message to write*/);
var listenPlan = Observable
  .When(authorizePlan)
  .Then(_ => networkStream.ReadObservable(10).Repeat());
var constantSizeMessageStream = Observable
  .When(listenPlan)
  .Switch();
```

EDIT: Allowed for networkStream to be set up